# Is it appropriate to use come up in that meaning?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

I wanted to express that something appeared very unexpectedly. Is it even possible to say something like that:

> The job came up very unexpectedly.

Comment: Idiomatically it's very common to say something [*came up unexpectedly*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22came+up+unexpectedly%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). But although it's not "wrong", I'd have to say I doubt many native speakers would normally use ***very*** there (if I wanted to add emphasis in such a context, I'd probably go for ***completely*** or ***totally***).

Comment: "Totally unexpectedly" is jarring to me because it's two "-ly" adverbs in a row. I don't know that I've ever heard that phrase said. "Totally unexpected," yes. "Totally unexpectedly," no.

Comment: Someone VtCed this as dictionary-def, but the first couple I tried (M-W, TFD) had nothing relevant, so this seems a little more interesting than just a bare lookup.

Comment: Instead of *very*, try *so* or *quite*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers To you, as a native speaker it sounds a little strange, doesn't it? I mean with very.

Comment: @Dmitry Bundin: Absolutely. But [rather unexpectedly](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=completely+unexpected%2Ctotally+unexpected%2Cvery+unexpected%2Crather+unexpected&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccompletely%20unexpected%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctotally%20unexpected%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cvery%20unexpected%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crather%20unexpected%3B%2Cc0), I now discover that it was in fact perfectly "normal" to use ***very*** in this context a couple of centuries ago. But I suggest learners today would do better to avoid it.

Comment: @user124384: You're quite right - as is Damkerng, who quite unexpectedly came up with the far more "natural" usage that simply didn't occur to me at the time.

Answer (score 1):

The job came up very unexpectedly.

If a job or opportunity comes up, it happens or becomes available.

There is nothing wrong with the sentence in question in light of this meaning.

Comment: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/come-up